# Should xhr.status === 0 trigger xhr.onerror?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Up until now I've been using the xhr.onerror callback to handle server failures on the client side. However, in my last tests xhr.status came back as 0, and the xhr.onerror callback was not triggered. Is and additional handler for xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 0 needed on top of xhr.onerror?

Comment: I think it depends on the reason why the status == 0

Comment: In this particular case it is a timeout in a CORS request.

Comment: it's not a timeout ... it's a CORS failure ... or, does `xhr.ontimeout` trigger?

Comment: It does, so I guess onerror doesn't run  since there is none, but ontimeout does. If you put it as an answer I'll mark it as the correct one.